# Specifying margin width manually

Tags: margins, koma-script

I'm trying to write my CV in LaTeX. I'm using a template which I got on-line. But the margins are huge. I need the top and bottom margin to be only 1 inch. The LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{varwidth}  
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\pagestyle{scrheadings}  
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\rmfamily\scshape}
% add the symbols for email and phone contact data
\cofoot{\so{Liefdestraat, 7 - 1234LI, Amsterdam, Nederland}\\ 
\so{ {\Large\Letter} jeff@gmail.com\ {\Large\Telefon} +31 (0)6 12345678}}
\begin{document}
...
```

Comment: have you looked at the `geometry` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While KOMA-Script classes recommend using the `typearea` package, one can still benefit from `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

will set one inch margins on all four sides.

Comment: fwiw, moderncv is a class in its own right, and has nothing to do with the koma-script bundle

Comment: @wasteofspace I've removed the tag.